# C# cannot insert data into SQL Server database

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm recently new at C# and follow a tutorial on connection to the database, the connection for viewing or `SELECT` command was ok, I made some revision based on the threads of forums to make my code better, but when I was in `INSERT` for my SQL Server, I have some problems. I was able to insert the data but when I re-run the program the data that I just inserted earlier was not in the database.

Here is my code on insert

```
string commandText = "INSERT INTO loginInfo (name, pass, role) VALUES(@name, @pass, @role)";

using (connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(commandText, connection);
    command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", textBox1.Text);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pass", textBox2.Text);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@role", textBox3.Text);

    try
    {
        command.Connection.Open();
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    catch
    {
    }
    finally
    {
        command.Connection.Close();
    }
}
```

I'm trying to create a simple CRUD but not save the data... please help

Comment: remove the empty catch block and check the exception. it should tell you what's wrong

Comment: Can you try to close connection after `ExecuteNonQuery` ?

Comment: +1 to @doerig . Never keep empty catches. Please try step by step debugging and check where u are getting the exception. Execute nonquery return 'int' that will tell you the status of insert, whether data is inserted or not.

Comment: @AbdellahOUMGHAR closing the connection has nothing to do with whether the command is executed or not. Besides, `using` *does* close the connection

Comment: I did but there where no error found, but if don't close the program the data is there, but when I close it and re-run the data will be gone

Comment: @yok2xDuran `using` will close the connection, you don't have to use that `finally` block. The entire `try/catch` block you used simply hides the error, nothing more

Comment: @yok2xDuran you are looking at different databases then. Are you using a file-based database perhaps, or LocalDB? What does the connection string look like?

Comment: Can you show us the **connection string** you're using, please? I suspect you might be using the `AttachDbFileName=` clause in there which is known to cause trouble

Comment: `WindowsFormsApplication2.Properties.Settings.Database1ConnectionString`  this what my connection string looks like

Comment: `AttachDbFileName=` uses a *file*. That file is copied from the source folder to Debug each time you debug your application. The `mdf` file inside the `Debug` folder will have the data you inserted until it gets overwritten. The source file though will always be empty

Comment: @yok2xDuran That's not a connection string. That's the property that contains the string. Post the *string* you entered in the `Database1ConnectionString ` setting

Comment: is this the connection string `connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True"`

Comment: @yok2xDuran then yes, you *are* looking at the wrong file and marc_s explains what happened in detail

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're using the `AttachDbFileName=` clause in your connection string, you might have fallen victim to a well-known issue : you might just be looking at the **wrong database (file)** when checking your data.

When running your app in Visual Studio, it will be copying around the `.mdf` file (from your `App_Data` directory to the output directory - typically `.\bin\debug` - where you app runs) and **most likely**, your `INSERT` works just fine - but you're just looking at the **wrong .mdf file** in the end!

If you want to stick with this approach, then try putting a breakpoint on the `connection.Close()` call - and then inspect the `.mdf` file with SQL Server Mgmt Studio Express - I'm almost certain your data is there.

The long-term viable solution in my opinion would be to:

1. install SQL Server Express (and you've already done that anyway)
2. install SQL Server Management Studio Express
3. create your database in **SSMS Express**, give it a logical name (e.g. `YourDatabase`)
4. connect to it using its logical **database name** (given when you create it on the server) - and don't mess around with physical database files and user instances. In that case, your connection string would be something like:

   ```
   Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=YourDatabase;Integrated Security=True
   ```

   and everything else is **exactly** the same as before...

Also see Aaron Bertrand's excellent blog post [Bad habits to kick: using AttachDbFileName](http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-attachdbfilename/) for more background info.

Comment: thanks it work, i installed SSMS Express and it worked, i thing the database that i use was a service-based database, i was able to add it by right clicking on the explorer and added the service-based database